# PHP, MySQL, and temporary tables

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

Php novice.

1.Is there anything wrong with this PHP & MySQL code?

```
include_once "db_login.php" ;

$sql = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_sap_id_select" ;
mysql_query ( $sql ) or ( "Error " . mysql_error () ) ;

$sql = " CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_sap_id_select 
               (
                 `current_page` INT NOT NULL,
                 `total_pages` INT NOT NULL,
                 `select_date` DATE NOT NULL,
                 `select_schcode` CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
                 `select_user` CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                 `select_id` CHAR(9) NOT NULL
               ) " ;
mysql_query ( $sql ) or ( "Error " . mysql_error () ) ;
```

2.Admittedly, I'm a dull boy, but I'll ask anyway: If I'm using a MySQL GUI and have open the target database, will it be aware of the above temporary table created by PHP/MySQL (IF the temporary table is properly created)?

Comment: Do u get any error message on execution of the script? If yes what s it?

Comment: Never ask "is there anything wrong", but only "how can I know if  there is anything wrong". Unfortunately, SO users don't have a PHP interpreter in their heads, to run your code on sight. On the other hand, your PHP will always tell you if there is anything wrong, if you let him

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't get an error, so I guess it is OK.

Comment: Do u have error_logging on in .ini file?

Comment: Do I get points just by asking a question?  My rep went up to 118 from 116.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Temporary tables are only visible to the connection used to create them, and they disappear once the connection is closed.

Comment: OK, that is good to know.  So my MySQL gui WOULD NOT see this temporary table, even if both connections (PHP and gui) were each still open separately and each used the same db login details.

Comment: Then using connection pool may be dangerous?

Comment: @Mohsen I think connection pool means you have a certain number of connections example 10 that you will be using, kind of a snigletton pattern that manage only N connections. if temporary table is persistent by connection then it wont disappear it will be stuck with one of the N open connections. (my guess)